# Handling Null Pointer while using lambda

Tags: java, java-8

Will below code ever get `nullPointerException` unless `e.getKey()` returns `null`

```
Map<Integer, Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>> spnCreationDetails;
Optional.ofNullable(spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey()).orElse(new SecurityAttributeChange()).getNewAttribute())
                                    .orElse(new SecurityAttr())
                                    .getUserName());
```

I am getting NPE in this line, is there anyway to debug this? I know `spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())` returns null, Am i missing anything in handling `null` over here?

---

**- EDIT**

---

Here is the almost complete method which will help to give input on how to refactor this so that it's readable.

```
private void updateAuditFields(List<SecurityAttributeChange> securityChanges, Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> result) {

    Map<Integer, Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>> spnModificationDetails = ...

    Map<Integer, Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>> spnCreationDetails = ...

    result.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
        e.getValue()
                .put("userIdLastChanged",
                        Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(spnModificationDetails.get(e.getKey()))
                                .orElse(Optional.of(new SecurityAttributeChange()))
                                .get()
                                .getNewAttribute()).orElse(new SecurityAttr()).getUserName());

        e.getValue()
                .put("lastChangedDatetime",
                        Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(spnModificationDetails.get(e.getKey()))
                                .orElse(Optional.of(new SecurityAttributeChange()))
                                .get()
                                .getNewAttribute()).orElse(new SecurityAttr()).getKnowledgeBeginDate());

        e.getValue()
                .put("userIdCreated", Optional.ofNullable(
                        Optional.ofNullable(spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())).orElse(Optional.of(new SecurityAttributeChange())).get().getNewAttribute())
                        .orElse(new SecurityAttr())
                        .getUserName());

        e.getValue()
                .put("createdDatetime",
                        Optional.ofNullable(Optional.ofNullable(spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey()))
                                .orElse(Optional.of(new SecurityAttributeChange()))
                                .get()
                                .getNewAttribute()).orElse(new SecurityAttr()).getKnowledgeBeginDate());

    });
}
```

Comment: its not null it's empty `Map<Integer, Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>> spnCreationDetails`

Comment: What does `SecurityAttributeChange` and `SecurityAttr` look like? When you create an instance with no-arg constructor, what are you doing inside it? What about the attributes then used with getters. More importantly, what does the exception log read?

Comment: Very good example of "how to make your code unreadable"

Comment: Suggessions are welcome @dieter

Comment: What is `e`? This looks much like it could be far simpler when knowing what you are actually doing.

Comment: e is Map.Entry object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())` can be null, you probably need:

```
Optional.ofNullable(spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey()))
        .orElse(new SecurityAttributeChange())
        .getNewAttribute()
        .orElse(new SecurityAttr())
        .getUserName();
```

i.e. `spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())` should be wrapped with an `Optional`.

EDIT: Seeing your comment, `spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())` can return either a `null` or an `Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>`, so it would be better to transform only the `null` into a new `Optional`:

```
spnCreationDetails.getOrDefault(e.getKey(),Optional.empty())
                  .orElse(new SecurityAttributeChange())
                  .getNewAttribute()
                  .orElse(new SecurityAttr())
                  .getUserName();
```

Comment: The OP said `spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey())` returns `Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>` so in your code `Optional.ofNullable(spnCreationDetails.get(e.getKey()))` would return an awkward `Optional<Optional<SecurityAttributeChange>>`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I see what you meant. Edited. Thanks.

Comment: Wondering what `new SecurityAttr().getUserName()` returns. As it would make more sense to use `spnCreationDetails.getOrDefault(e.getKey(),Optional.empty()) .flatMap( SecurityAttributeChange::getNewAttribute) .map(SecurityAttr::getUserName) .orElse(???)` whereas `???` has to be filled with whatever default `new SecurityAttr().getUserName()` returns…